# How to disable list of dates in <ion-datetime> (Ionic 4)?

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to disable a list of dates in ion-datetime. I have tried the disabled-value but it disables the whole date component. I want to disable only the specific dates.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" pickerFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="startdate"
          formControlName="from" [min]="minStartDate()" [max]="enddate" placeholder="mm/dd/yy"></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I don't think that's possible in ionic.
But, I have come across a great plugin that can achieve what you want:
[ionic4-datepicker-component](https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ionic4-datepicker-component/)
One of the options can achieve exactly what you want.

> disabledDates(Optional) array: pass dates array if you like to make them disable from the
> selection.

Now,, I haven't tried it myself yet but if you've managed to work it out, please share your answer here, so it can benefits others.

Cheers.